# JSONObject["featured_image"] is not a String

Tags: java, json, wordpress

Hi all I am getting a following json from Wordpress rest APi Call

```
   [
        {
            "ID": 248,
            "post_title": "test post",
            "post_author": "admin",
            "excerpt": "",
            "url": "http://localhost/wp-learning/?p=248",
            "permalink": "http://192.168.10.31/wp-learning/test-post/",
            "post_date": "2017-08-07 09:15:57",
            "comment_count": "2",
            "category": [
                {
                    "term_id": 1,
                    "name": "Uncategorized",
                    "slug": "uncategorized",
                    "term_group": 0,
                    "term_taxonomy_id": 1,
                    "taxonomy": "category",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "count": 1,
                    "filter": "raw",
                    "cat_ID": 1,
                    "category_count": 1,
                    "category_description": "",
                    "cat_name": "Uncategorized",
                    "category_nicename": "uncategorized",
                    "category_parent": 0
                }
            ],
            "views": "4",
            "featured_image": false
        },
        {
            "ID": 247,
            "post_title": "The Coolest Vanity Apps for You and Your Girls",
            "post_author": "admin",
            "excerpt": "",
            "url": "http://td_uid_79_598817d2cebf2",
            "permalink": "http://192.168.10.31/wp-learning/the-coolest-vanity-apps-for-you-and-your-girls/",
            "post_date": "2017-08-07 07:33:38",
            "comment_count": "0",
            "category": [
                {
                    "term_id": 15,
                    "name": "Beauty",
                    "slug": "beauty",
                    "term_group": 0,
                    "term_taxonomy_id": 15,
                    "taxonomy": "category",
                    "description": "On each category you can set a Category template style, a Top post style (grids) and a module type for article listing.",
                    "parent": 14,
                    "count": 17,
                    "filter": "raw",
                    "cat_ID": 15,
                    "category_count": 17,
                    "category_description": "On each category you can set a Category template style, a Top post style (grids) and a module type for article listing.",
                    "cat_name": "Beauty",
                    "category_nicename": "beauty",
                    "category_parent": 14
                }
            ],
            "views": "0",
            "featured_image": "http://192.168.10.31/wp-learning/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/3.jpg"
        }
]
```

I am problem in fetching the tag name "featured_image". what type of datatype is it? i tried

```
jsonObj.getString("featured_image");
```

for this it gave me error  JSONObject["featured_image"] is not a String.
also

```
resultsObj.getJSONObject("featured_image").toString()
```

for this it gave me error JSONObject["featured_image"] is not a JSONObject.

Comment: are you using simpleJson? also, where does the json object come from?

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe a `JSONBoolean`? It's a boolean for sure.

Comment: yes it is simple json, but result wordpress is sometimes string or boolean

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `resultsObj.getJSONObject("featured_image").toString()` which asks to get a JSON Object out of the Key/Value at 'featured_image'.

But we can see that the value is a string, or a bool:

```
"featured_image": "http://192.168.10.31/wp-learning/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/3.jpg"

"featured_image": false
```

So you should not call `getJSONObject()` on this key, at all.

Comment: Should i put a condition for bool check?

Comment: If you know that 'featured_image' is always a string or a bool then you should just never call `getJSONObject()` on it, no matter the check you do. `getJSONObject` is to get a structured object. Instead, use `getString()`. Only then, yes, maybe a bool check could be useful.

Comment: i tried jsonObj.getString("featured_image"); but it still gave me error

Comment: Because you most probably did not perform the call on the "category" array entry but on the root of your document...

Comment: it is outside the category array.

Comment: My bad, did not see. Yes, add a bool check before getString() and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSON Structure, it looks like the "featured_image" is of boolean type, it is not string or object.

Comment: how do i fetch the value? should i check for boolean false condition?

Comment: I got your point. Please check my recent answer. Hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think its inner json problem 
try like this :

```
JSONObject category = jsonObj.getJSONObject("category");

category.getJSONObject("featured_image");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, I didn't tested but that can be helpful in determining the data type and based on the type you can decide which method needs to be called.

So use:

```
JsonValue type = resultsObj.get("featured_image").getValueType();
if (type.getValueType() == JsonValue.ValueType.TRUE || type.getValueType() == JsonValue.ValueType.FALSE){
 // call boolean method
  boolean bValue = resultsObj.get("featured_image").getAsBoolean()

}else{
   //based on you type you can call respective method.
}
```

Refer following link:
[JsonValueType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.ValueType.html)

[getValueType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html#getValueType--)